# regular expression not valid, finding match between <<>>

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im scanning a document for a set of markers that will then be replaced based on data in my spreadsheet.
The markers are the same as my column headers but incased by << >>.
e.g. <<name>> <<age>>
in the case there is no data to replace these the marker is replaced with <<XXXX>>.

my code for this looks as follows:

```
var marker = "<<"+headers[0][col]+">>"  
 var x = bodyFinal.findText(marker);
 if(x!=null && !row[r][col]){//match found but nothing to replace I.E. COL DATA EMPTY
   bodyFinal.replaceText(marker,"XXXX");
 }else{
   bodyFinal.replaceText(marker,row[r][col]);
 }
```

What i would like to do is to scan the document for potential misspelt markers or any other marker that doesnt match the column headers, but that isnt the replaced marker <<XXXX>>

Using the site https://regexr.com/3gobr I ended up with the following regular expression:

> /<<(?!XXXX)(.*?)>>/g

However, when I implement in the same way as previously stated I get an error stating this in an invalid regular expression.

Is this an issue with the way the regular expression is written or is the issue potentially else where?

**Additional info**

due to some confusion about my question I shall expand further. I am changing the name of some of the variables and other things in order to simplify the example.

my document will have look something like this:

> Dear <<name>>

> Due to your age being <<age>>, we are unable to accept your application. please look at our other job posting to find a suitable match.
> You can find these at the following <<URK>>

> Yours Sincerelly, <<Mager>>

In this example the markers for name and age match the column header in my spreadsheet and therefore will be correctly identified using the sample code posted above.

Lets say a single row of data looks like this:

| Name | Age | URL | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Harry |  | [www.morejobs.com](http://www.morejobs.com) | Dumbledore |

As the data in the age column is empty this will be replaced with <<XXXX>> Making my document look as foolows:

> Dear Harry

> Due to your age being <<XXXX>>, we are unable to accept your application. please look at our other <<Job>> posting to find a suitable match.
> You can find these at the following <<URK>>

> Yours Sincerelly, <<Mager>>

I then want to scan the document again to find any markers which werent properly itendified, be this because they were misspelt (as with URL and Manager) or added by mistake (as with Job), but not include the markers replaced with XXXX

This list will later be output as an error report for the user. I'm thinking it will be as a HTML UI dialog. For now simply storing them in an array will suffice.

This will look something like this.

> The following markers where found but could not be replaced:
> <<Job>>, <<URK>>, <<Mager>>

**Further Edit**

I am still unable to achieve the desired results so I'm adding a larger extent of my code. I also realise that in the code above there is an error.

```
bodyFinal.replaceText(marker,"XXXX");
```

This looks for replaces the empty data markers with XXXX and not <>.

Non the less, the results arent achieved.

Here is the expanded code:

```
//LOOP HEADERS TO REPLACE MARKERS
var empty = [];
for(var col in headers[0]){ 
  var bodyFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId).getBody(); //get again to scan 
  var marker = "<<"+headers[0][col]+">>"  
  var x = bodyFinal.findText(marker);
  if(x!=null && !row[r][col]){//match found but nothing to replace I.E. COL DATA EMPTY
      Logger.log(marker +" not replaced");
      empty.push(marker);
      bodyFinal.replaceText(marker,"<<XXXX>>"); 
  }else{//if date, format to dd/MM/yyy
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call(row[r][col]) == "[object Date]"){
      var date = row[r][col];
      date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "GMT-4", "dd/MM/yyyy"); //This may need to account for summer time 
      bodyFinal.replaceText(marker,date);
    }else{
      bodyFinal.replaceText(marker,row[r][col]);
    }
   }
  }

//LOOK FOR ALL MARKERS NOT MATCHED, NOT INCLUDING EMPTY DATA REPLACEMENT MARKERS <<XXXX>>    
 bodyFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId).getBody(); //get again to scan
 var markerErr = "/<<[^(XXXX)]+?>>/g";

 var x = bodyFinal.findText(markerErr);
 if( x==null){
   Logger.log("Row: "+r+" no mismatched markers");
 }else{
   Logger.log("Row: "+r+" has missmatched markers: "+x.getElement());
 }
//KEEP TRACK OF EMPTY DATA MARKERS AND MARKERS NOT REPLACED
 markerLog.push(x); 
 errorLog.push(empty.length);
}

Logger.log("errors: "+errorLog);
Logger.log("markers: "+markerLog);
```

The output I get is:

> Row: 0 no mismatched markers
> marker <<age>> not replaced
> marker <<date>> not replaced
> Row: 1 no mismatched markers
> errors: 2,0
> markers: ,

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `What i would like to do is to scan the document for potential misspelt markers or any other marker that doesnt match the column headers`, I cannot understand about your goal. And also, I cannot understand about your script. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect?

Comment: Additional info has been added, @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if got you right. Suppose you want to change every tag ('header') in the text with `<<XXXX>>` in cases when given tag is not equal with some tags in your set. In a simplest case it could be done this way:

```js
var text = `The markers <<are>> the same as my <<column>>
headers but incased by << >>. e.g. <<name>> <<age>> in the
case there is no data to replace these the marker is replaced with <<XXXX>>.`

var headers = ["name", "age"];
var regex = "<<(?!" + headers.join(">)(?!") + ">).+?>";
var marker = new RegExp(regex, "g");

console.log(text.replace(marker, "<<XXXX>>"));
```

As you can see in the output all 'wrong' tags were changed with `<<XXXX>>`. All the 'headers' were omitted. Probably it's not the best solution, but it works to some extent.

**Updated variant:**

```js
var text = `Dear <<name>>

Due to your age being <<age>>, we are unable to accept your application.
Please look at our other job posting to find a suitable match.
You can find these at the following <<URK>>

Yours Sincerelly, <<Mager>>`;

var headers = [ "Name", "Age", "URL", "Manager" ];
var row     = [ "Harry", "", "www.morejobs.com", "Dumbledore" ];

// Step 1. Replace all valid headers in the text
for (var i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
    var find_for = new RegExp("<<" + headers[i] + ">>", "gi");
    var replace_to = (row[i] != "") ? row[i] : "<<XXXX>>";
    text = text.replace(find_for, replace_to);
}

console.log(text);

// Step 2. Get all wrong headers from the text
var wrong_headers = text.match(/<<[^(XXXX)]+?>>/g);

console.log(wrong_headers);
```

**Update 2**

Sorry, I failed to untangle the script in the question. There is something too complicated out there. I'd prefer to stick with something much simple.

Here is the working code:

```
function main() {
  var body    = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var headers = [ "Name", "Age", "URL", "Manager" ];
  var row     = [ "Harry", "", "www.morejobs.com", "Dumbledore" ];

  var search_for = headers.map(x => "<<" + x + ">>");
  var replace_to = row.map(x => x == "" ? "<<XXXX>>" : x);
  
  search_for.forEach((x, i) => body.replaceText("(?i)" + x, replace_to[i]));
  
  var mismatched_markers = body.getText().match(/<<[^(XXXX)]+?>>/g) || [];
  Logger.log(mismatched_markers);
}
```

Feel free to add any telemetry, summertime correction, and whatnot.

Comment: Ive added extra details to my question to better clarify

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. I still can't solve the issue and have updated my question with more code.

Comment: Ok. See Update 2